# Navigation Engine not able to process request

Tags: java, endeca

I get the following error in Endeca:

```
com.endeca.navigation.ENEException: Navigation Engine not able to process 
request `http://myhost:15000/search?terms=remote&rank=0&offset=0&irversion=601`
```

My MDEX version is 6.3.0

The referenced jar files in my app is:

`endeca_navigation.jar` : Specification-IR-Version: 6.3.0 (Read from MANIFEST file)
`endeca_logging.jar`: Specification-Version: 6.1.2 (Read from MANIFEST file)

Even with these referenced jars, why is the request parameter still `irversion=601`?
I'm using java 1.5 and building my app in eclipse. At first, it was referencing older jar files (601), but i removed those completely and replaced them with the newer jar files listed above. I've rebuilt my app and I still see the parameter irversion=601. I've been trying to find out what the issue is for a few hours, but i'm having no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If nothing else I think that you need an N=0 parameter for you request to work.

Also if you are using an application server like Weblogic to run you app, it has a tendency of caching referenced jars which may have to be cleared for it to pick up the new versions of the jars.

Finally if all else fails there is a --back_compat 601 parameter on your dgraph which indicated the accepatble navigation.jar versions. You can use this parameter to determine if the issue is the jar version or something else in between.

Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to Wiszh's response, it is useful to take a look at the dgraph request query logs (located in /logs/dgraph/Dgraphxx/Dgraphxx.log and .reqlog) which will show a more specific error and the query that caused it.

Answer (score 0):

Do your jars match the version of Endeca server you are querying?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to an old navigation api jar in your class path

Check the `ToolsAndFrameworks\version\assembler\lib` to get the correct version of navigation api jar. That should fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

correct jar path fixed the issue for me
ToolsAndFrameworks\version\assembler\lib